# Message Stream Modified (41) or Timeout for kafka client

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos

I am having some issue with a kafka client configuration using kerberos to authenticate from a realm to the realm of the kafka brokers.

I receive the error Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
**Message stream modified (41)**

I found on the internet to edit the krb5.conf file and delete the **renew_lifetime property**. Once I do that, the call to kafka brokers goes in timeout, even if kerberos commit is done successfully.

I am using the same principal that other kafka clients use in the same realm to obtain service from the same kafka brokers, so I don't understand why it should be different.

I tried to add this option: **sun.security.krb5.disablereferrals=true** to the java.security file of the client, but nothing changed.

Can you help me? Any idea?

Sorry I am new and have only a little experience.

Comment: _"same principal that other kafka clients use in the same realm"_ >> do you also use the same exact `krb5.conf`, with entries for the realms of client principal / service principals and any realms in between (e.g. `CLIENT.MY.ORG` > `MY.ORG` > `SERVICES.MY.ORG`) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The krb5.conf file was exactly the same. Later I did some edits, adding cross-realm authentication, but nothing changed, since the principal was issued by the KDC of realm B, for the client in realm A. Also other clients in realm A use this same principal issued by KDC in realm B. The principal is in this form user/realmB@realmB. I don't know why but it seems to work. In "KDC realm B" logs I see that the client in realm A ask for kbgtgt/realmB@realmB and then ask for TGS_REQ for kafka service.The problem is last client goes in timeout, even if it ask for TGS_REQ.

Comment: The reason is that the client must hop from realmB to "realm root" _(unless you have non-default CAPath rules)_ to get a right-of-passage to realmA, then to realmA to get the service ticket. The timeout suggest a network issue: can you check that you can physically reach port 88 on all KDC servers involved? On Linux use `nc` both on TCP and UDP (unless `krb5.conf` disables UDP).

Comment: On second thoughts I would bet my money on UDP 88 being blocked by an idiotic security policy on the machine, or on a router/switch/firewall/proxy/load balancer that the machine happens to use.